# Paying damages for rerouting flood to neighbor's property

Tags: choshen-mishpat-civil-law, water, torts-damages

Are you obligated to pay for damage done to a neighbor's property if you redirect a river from flooding your property which then hits another house down the street. (i.e. You place sandbags in front of your house)

Comment: There are two ways of doing that: if you only protect your property passively, you're free, but if you actively push the water into you neighbor's direction you're liable. Pleading sandbags is the former, so you're free.

Comment: Hmmm...you're on the opposite side of the US I thought you would be, given the timing of this question.  It is possible to redirect a small river with a wall (or a large river with a very large wall) but placing sandbags in front of your house will at most raise the outdoor water level a smidge.  All you're doing is keeping the water from crossing the threshold of your doorway.  It would take an awful lot of sandbags to seal off an entire property (like a wall) enough to redirect the water.  (1 of 2)

Comment: Even if you're in a townhouse with the neighbor's door 2' away, if the water is high enough to reach your sandbags, then the area is quite flooded anyway.  Your keeping water out of your doorway won't change the water that hits your neighbor's doorway in any appreciable way.  But you said "down the street."  Unless you're getting sandbags by the thousands, you can't really do what you say you're doing. (2 of 2)